# Incorrect scheme in .NET core app when request goes through reverse-proxy

Tags: .net, apache, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

I have apache working as reverse-proxy. Behind apache there is .NET core application. Both use HTTPS.
The problem is, that when I access this .NET app through proxy, .NET reports that request was made without SSL using http.

Apache proxy config:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass "https://domain:8444/"
    ProxyPassReverse "https://domain:8444/"
</Location>
```

Apache is accessible via https://domain/.

When I access app through https://domain:8444/ address, then `httpContext.Request.IsHttps==true` and `httpContext.Request.Scheme=="https"`, but when I access app through https://domain/ then `httpContext.Request.IsHttps==false` and `httpContext.Request.Scheme=="http"`.

When I try the same configuration with PHP, everything works OK.
Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Your apache isn't sending the correct header to your application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to make sure your apache is setting the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers.

Second you need to make your ASP.NET Core application aware of it. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction#configure-a-reverse-proxy-server):

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

This already happens in the `UseIISIntegration()` (see [source](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration/IISSetupFilter.cs#L27)), but you may have removed that (or it not being set in the template you used).

Comment: After some digging, it turned out that .NET changes schema to http when `X-Forwarded-For` or `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers are present. So adding `UseForwardedHeaders` indeed solves problem, but I personally think there is a bug in .NET. Schema is changed to http always, regardles `X-Forwarded-Proto` value. And, by definition, `X-Forwarded-Proto` is actually protocol that a client used to connect to proxy, so if I don't set up `UseForwardedHeaders` I should always see HTTPS. When `UseForwardedHeaders` is set, and `X-Forwarded-Proto` is HTTP, then schema should be changed to HTTP.

Comment: Kestrel always accepts only http by default. With the more recent versions you can set a https port and encryption too. When developing, the IISExpress usually does the ssl connection (if set up) and the `UseIISIntegration()` registers the forward headers usage. in practice the reverse proxy is the ssl termination point and the data behind the reverse proxy is sent plaintext, as its easier to handle (you don't need to handle ssl certiciates per app and can let the proxy handle it, when you change the ssl keys, you only do it on the proxy).

Comment: Also your services behind the proxy don't need to waste cpu cycles on encryption and decryption

Comment: @Tseng the problem is that other parts of the framework rely on Request.Scheme .  For example, the OpenIDConnect and OAuth providers will build a redirect url based on this scheme.  So even though the user browses to https://foo.com, it will redirect to https://authprovider.com?redirecturi=http://foo.com, since as Krysztof notes scheme is always http.  The code above doesn't seem to fix this for me..

Comment: @Daniel: I didn't test, but the `Request.Scheme` should be updated, when forwarding headers are used and `X.Forwarded-Proto` is set to https by the proxy

Comment: @Tseng -I would expect that, but this was not the behavior I was seeing.  In some scenarios, Request.Scheme can be http, even if XForwardedProto = https.  My setup was dotnet core 1.1, IIS, and WAP.  Updating to 2.0 seems to have fixed this.  I believe the issue was this one: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/140  (different number of X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto headers) and has been fixed in 2.0